# What's wrong with my C code? (Prime factors of a big number)

Tags: c, for-loop, factorization

Could you please help me?

I'm a beginner at C and my code doesn't work.

I'm trying to determine largest prime factor of 600851475143 and when I run the code, it just does nothing. Trying with smaller number however works.

```
long i;

for (i = 600851475143; i > 1; i--)
{
    if (600851475143 % i == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
};
```

Comment: Does nothing?  Or just takes a *ridiculously long time* to complete the `for` loop?  If I'm reading correctly, it wouldn't print the first line until halfway through the loop, right?

Comment: There are many similar questions like this one on Stack Overflow: https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+c+prime+factor

Comment: Is it not working or just taking a really long time to finish? That's a really big number

Comment: don't start loop from number itself, start from half of that number, it will reduce the time but will not change the result

Comment: Literally does nothing but "Press any key to continue"

Comment: @MikeChristensen Wouldn't it print the number itself the first time through the loop?

Comment: If it's a 32-bit processor, then that number (`600851475143`) is an overflow and it's likely negative and failing `i > 1` test. Try `long long i;`.

Comment: @CDspace - Yup, you're right about that.  First iteration would be 0, then another 0 halfway through.  Gotta be a 32bit issue.  I'm not really a C expert.

Comment: You should put a break; statement after the printf to exit the loop as the first match is found. The last semicolon is not required

Comment: 1) Tried running from half the loop. Smart idea, gotta admit that. But it still does nothing.

Comment: Long long worked! Now it takes ridiculously long time..

Comment: @user2739184 - not much point testing against *even* values of `(i)`, or any value of `(i)` larger than the square root of 600851475143. If you have a factor, you can find the other (larger) factor with a division.

Comment: To continue on what Brett Hale said, it will be likely to be ***much*** faster to find all the primes below the square root of your test number using one of the [well known ways of finding prime numbers quickly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429694/Finding-prime-numbers) then only testing those prime numbers to see if `600851475143 % testPrime == 0`

Comment: Also note that, just because `x % i == 0` does not mean that `i` is a *prime* factor of `x` - only that it is a factor... In order to find the largest prime factor, you have to find the largest factor that has no other factors than 1 and itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the correct way to print a `long` is not `%d` but `%ld` (d = decimal, ld = long decimal). If `long` and `int` have different sizes on your system (which is not unusual), the results would not print correctly to begin with.

Next possible problem is that `600851475143` is more than fits into a `32 bit` variable, yet `long` is only guaranteed to be at least `32 bit`. It may be bigger than that, but only `32 bits` are guaranteed. So are you sure that `long` is big enough on your system?

Try

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));
```

if it says `8`, everything is fine, if it says only `4`, `long` is not sufficient and you need to use `long long` instead (and `%lld` for `printf`, lld = long long decimal).

Last but not least, you are aware that your loop needs to do 600 billion iterations, aren't you? Even if you have a very fast system with a very fast CPU this will take quite some time to complete. So you will see `600851475143` printed to the screen immediately, but it will take quite some time before your code terminates (or finds another divisor, in case this is not a prime number).

Optionally:
Instead of writing `600851475143`, you may write `600851475143LL` to let the compiler know you want this number to be of type `long long`. It seems like the C 2011 standard doesn't require this any longer (numbers are automatically treated as `long` or `long long` if required), yet I know that pior to C 2011 some compilers least issued a warning for numbers being bigger than `int` (or bigger than `long`).

Comment: Thank you, code now works, but takes pretty much about forever. So, you were right, much apprecieted.

Comment: Integer constants in C are not always `int`. Per C 2011 6.4.4.1 5, the type of an unsuffixed decimal constant is the first in the following list in which its value can be represented: `int`, `long int`, `long long int`. Per paragraph 6, it may also be an extended type, if necessary.

Comment: @user2739184 Well, now you know why huge prime numbers play such an important role in data encryption. There is no "super fast way" to get all prime factors of a certain number and if a number is build out of two prime numbers, both 1024 bits in size or larger, guess how long it will take to find those using an approach like you did above ;-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the info. I changed the reply accordingly. Prior to C 2011 at least `long long` numbers required `LL` with some compilers, though usually this only caused warnings and the compiled code was still correct.

Comment: FYI `%zu` is the correct format specifier for `size_t`, you don't need the typecast for `sizeof` in that case.

Comment: @tristopia You are, of course, right but I was pretty sure that whatever value sizeof returns here will be small enough to fit into an `int` ;-) But maybe I should fix that and if it is only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a 32-bit system. The number `600851475143` is bigger than 32 bits.

Instead of `long i` try:

```
long long i;
```

And instead of `printf("%d\n", i);` try:

```
printf("%lld\n", i);
```

And use `600851475143LL` in place of `600851475143`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your loop with the greatest integer less than or equal to the square root of your large number. Then you can find factor pairs working down through the loop. Write a separate function to check whether a given number is prime. If the larger factor of the pair is prime, return it. If the larger is not prime, check if the smaller is prime and if so return it.